# how to compare string in SQL without using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-matching

I am using SQL query shown below to compare AMCcode. But if I compare the AMCcode '1' using LIKE operator it will compare all the entries with AMCcode 1, 10,11,12,13. .. 19, 21,31.... etc. But I want to match the AMCcode only with 1. Please suggest how can I do it. The code is given below :

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PM.PA_AMCCode), '') like          
  (        
   CASE         
    WHEN @AMCCode IS NULL THEN '%'        
    ELSE '%'+@AMCCode+ '%'        
   END        
  )
```

This is part of the code where I need to replace the LIKE operator with any other operator which will give the AMCcode with 1 when I want to search AMCcode of 1, not all 10,11,12..... Please help

Comment: Please, clarify your question. If you need exact match - then why do you use `like` operator instead of equality?

Comment: I'm not positive but you might want to take a look at PATINDEX or CHARINDEX, although I believe they only return an INT, being the location your pattern starts.

Comment: yes I need exact match.. . I used equality but it showed no records.. but there are records

Comment: @gautamshetty Can you post your query you tried using an equality match. Along with samples of what the actual codes look like. If you include sample data and an expected outcome. It's much easier to help with your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
where ',' + cast(PM.PA_AMCCode as varchar(255)) + ',' like '%,' + @AMCCodes + ',%'
```

This includes the delimiters in the comparison.

Note that a better method is to split the string and use a `join`, something like this:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select cast(code as int) as code
      from dbo.split(@AMCCodes, ',') s(code)
     ) s
where t.AMCCode = s.code;
```

This is better because under some circumstances, this version can make use of an index on `AMCCode`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exactly match the value, you don't need to use '%' in your query. You can just use like as below

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PM.PA_AMCCode), '') like          
  (        
   CASE         
    WHEN @AMCCode IS NULL THEN '%'        
    ELSE @AMCCode        
   END        
  )
```

Possibly you can remove case statement and query like

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PM.PA_AMCCode), '') like @AMCCode
```